# How to add user input to array or remove it? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I get user input. If what they type in is not already in the array(how do I check an array?), add it to the array.
And vice versa how do I remove something from an array given the user input.

Example:

```
string teams[] = {"St. Louis,","Dallas","Chicago,","Atlanta,"};

cout <<"What is the name of the city you want to add?" << endl;
    cin >> add_city;

 cout <<"What is the name of the city you want to remove?" << endl;
    cin >> remove_city;
```

Comment: You've got some extra commas in your `teams` array. Also, as mentioned below, using `[]` doesn't make the array variable-length; it makes its length depend on the length of the initializer list, in this case 4. From that point on, it's the same as a fixed-length array. `std::vector` is what you *really* want.

Comment: The comments are on purpose. I am learning arrays and told only to use arrays...

Comment: I said *commas* not comments. E.g. `"St. Louis,"` should be `"St. Louis"`.

Comment: I'm confused. Arrays are fixed length. Thus "add it to the array" makes no sense; no matter what length you pick, at some point you can run out of slots. Now if you are supposed to use arrays *on the heap,* then you want the second paragraph of Dietmar's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array, you could treat empty array cells with a char* such as "EMPTY". To find an item you search through the array , and find to "replace" or add it.

```
const char * Empty = "EMPTY";
cout << "Please enter a city you want to add:"
cin >> city;
for(int i = 0; i < Arr_Size; i++) //variable to represent size of array
{
    if(Arr[i] == Empty) //check for any empty cells you want to add
    {
       //replace cell
    }
    else if(i == Arr_Size-1) //if on last loop
       cout << "Could not find empty cell, sorry!";
}
```

As for removing a cell:

```
cout << "Please enter the name of the city you would like to remove: ";
cin >> CityRemove;

for(int i = 0; i < Arr_Size; i++)
{
    if(Arr[i] == CityRemove)
    {
        Arr[i] = Empty;             //previous constant to represent your "empty" cell
    }
    else if(i == Arr_Size - 1)    //on last loop, tell the user you could not find it.
    {
        cout << "Could not find the city to remove, sorry!";
    }
}
```

Printing the array while skipping the 'empty' cells
    //Printing the array

```
for(int i = 0; i < Arr_Size; i++)
{
    if(Arr[i] != Empty)             //if the cell isnt 'empty'
    {
        cout << Arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

But i do agree using a vector would be a much more efficient approach, this is simply a creative approach to get your mind thinking.

Comment: Why not use a zero-length string, i.e. `""`?

Comment: edited the post to show my intent, when printing it skips the 'empty' cells.

Comment: It looks to me like you've declared `Arr` as `std::vector<std::string> Arr;`... you should show that. `string Arr[]` would not work because there's no `size` method for built-in arrays.

Comment: Im using Arr to represent an array, and size a function to show the size of the array, ill edit the loops. I usually make size functions for arrays in my programs.

Answer (score 4):

The size of built-in arrays is immutable: You can neither remove elements not can you add any. I would recommend using a `std::vector<std::string>`, instead: Adding elements to a `std::vector<T>` can, e.g., be done using `push_back()`. To remove an element you would locate an element, e.g., using `std::find()`, and then use `erase()` to remove it.

If you need to use built-in arrays (although I don't see any good reason for this), you'd allocate an array on the heap using `new std::string[size]` and maintain its size, appropriately releasing memory at opportune times using `delete[] array;`.

Comment: +1. Vectors are definitely the way to go if you want things to be dynamic, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To add information to an array, you could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the city's name: " << std::endl;
    std::getline(cin, myArray[i]);
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by removing something from an array. Do you want to set the element's value to 0, which would result in something like {"City 1", "City 2", 0, "City 3}. Or do you want to remove it from the array and move the other elements to fill its space, which would result in something like {"City 1", "City 2", "City 3"}?

Comment: It's an array of `string`, not `const char*`, so I'm not sure that having nulls in the initializer list will work.